# iOS Facebook 3.1 API - "Posted by" not showing our app

Tags: ios, facebook, ios6

I just finished integrating the Facebook 3.1 API into our app, and have left the flow the same except for the native posting UI. When I'm on an iOS 6 device, wall posts from our app now say "via iOS" and we're not showing up as an authorized application. When I post from iOS 5, we show up as an authorized app and the wall post shows up with our app name.

I'm assuming that the difference here is on iOS 5 we're doing the graph request ourselves, whereas in iOS 6, iOS is doing it for us. Is there any way to have the same behavior on both iOS 5 and iOS 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the native posting UI (SLComposeViewController) will always say via iOS as behind the scenes it uses the native iOS Facebook connection's token, not your token. I presume in the previous incarnation, you wrote your own posting view controller. Best stick with that and use the SLRequest class, which is pretty much the same as the old way, except that the token is handled via the Accounts framework.